# ASP.NET MVC 5 HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, http-post

I have controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ItemIndex()
    {

        List<Item> item = RepositoryFactory.Create<IItemRepository>().ItemList();

        return View(item);
    }
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ItemIndex(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        foreach( string key in formCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            Response.Write("Key" + key);
            Response.Write(formCollection[key]);


        }
        return View();
    }
```

And view for that:

```
@model List<Kev.Models.Item>

<div style="font-family:Arial">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => item.Start)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => item.Start)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Start)
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Repository have DbContext with Item inside. 
And what i want to do is fill this textboxes in View, and submit changes to update existing DataBase with this values. 
What i did for now is not working code, i cant even make this HttpPost work. 
It popup NullReferenceException for >>Model inside @foreach and not sure how to fix that.

Comment: in view or controller exception coming?

Comment: oh i forget to pass something to return View();, now it dont throw nullReference but error look like: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Kev.Models.Item]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Kev.Models.Item]'.

Comment: are you passing ``List<Item>``?? make sure

Comment: List<Item> item = RepositoryFactory.Create<IItemRepository>().ItemList().ToList();

Comment: Yea now it works, but now how i can convert formCollection items to List of <Item> ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `foreach` to `for` loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<Model.Count;i++)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Start)
  @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Start)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Start)
}
```

and change your action parameter form `FormCollection` to `List<Item>`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemIndex(List<Kev.Models.Item> model)
{
   return View();
}
```